# Incompatibilities among your library dependencies after up-gradation from play 2.4 version to play 2.5.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, deadbolt

I have recently upgraded my project from play framework 2.4.0 to 2.5.0 and when I build it I am getting so many library incompatibilities issue which I am unsure about how to resolve it. Can anyone has any idea how can we resolve such issues.

I am just sharing the sample as list is quite big:

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies
[warn] Here are some of the libraries that were evicted:
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-netty-server_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
[warn]  * com.typesafe.play:play-server_2.11:2.4.0 -> 2.5.0
```

I have noticed that all above warns are coming because I am using deadbolt2 library version as:

```
"be.objectify" % "deadbolt-java_2.11" % "2.4.4"
```

If I remove above dependency then all warns go away. There is not other latest version available for deadbolt2. Not sure what I should do now. Please suggest.

Comment: This could help investigate the issue: https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: @rethab: I completely understand your point that dependency graph will help in understanding the issue but my point is I have no where specified play-netty-server, play-java, play-server version as dependency in builds.sbt file, I tried adding explicitly adding these dependencies in builds.sbt file with correct version as 2.5.0 even then am getting same errors, so it seems to me that the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It helps you identify where the 'offending' dependency is coming from.

Comment: @rethab: Its the deadbolt library version which is conflicting. I am using latest deadbolt2 library dependency as: "be.objectify" % "deadbolt-java_2.11" % "2.4.4". There is not other latest dependency available as of now. Now sure what to do

Comment: Raise the issue with them. Propose a change.

Comment: 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT has been available for quite a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning in Deadbolt follows the same x.y version of Play, so Deadbolt 2.4 is for Play 2.4, Deadbolt 2.5 is for Play 2.5 and so on.

Deadbolt 2.5.0 was released today, so if you update your version to `"be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-scala" % "2.5.0"` you should be fine.

This is documented [here](https://deadbolt-java.readme.io/docs).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for looking at this questions and trying to help me in this. It's was actually the deadbolt 2 dependency that I was using with Playframework 2.5.0.

I was using:

```
"be.objectify" % "deadbolt-java_2.11" % "2.4.4"
```

Now am using below, which has actually solved the issue:

```
"be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.5.0"
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `-SNAPSHOT` bit, 2.5.0 has been released.

Comment: @SteveChaloner: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Did you `reload` in activator to pick up the changes?

Comment: Try again and check your dependency tree.  2.5.0 and 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT are identical apart from the version name.